# Need to have individual XSD's - But want them to reference/use a generic structure response XSD

Tags: xml, xsd

I am using Spring 3.1

I have a generic response XSD that I use as a response for several request types. I now have a new requirement, where each of these requests need to have an individual response type. But what I want is for these new responses to have the same structure of the generic response. The attributes ect are the same, the only change is the name, i.e. `<xs:element name="itemOneResponse">`

My generic response - **genericResponse.xsd**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="http://me.com" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
    <xs:element name="genericResponse">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="responseCode" type="xs:int"/>
                <xs:element name="errorCode" type="xs:int"/>
                <xs:element name="errorDescription" type="xs:string"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

I have 3 new individual responses that are the same as the generic response, but have a different name. One example is below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="http://me.com" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
    <xs:element name="itemOneResponse">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="responseCode" type="xs:int"/>
                <xs:element name="errorCode" type="xs:int"/>
                <xs:element name="errorDescription" type="xs:string"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

How can I get the new custom responses to reference the genericResponse.xsd schema and it's elements?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0):

Define a single `xs:complexType` with a `name` attribute, and then refer to that `xs:complexType` using the `type` attribute of `xs:element`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="http://me.com" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
    <xs:element name="itemOneResponse" type="genericResponse"/>
    <xs:element name="itemTwoResponse" type="genericResponse"/>
    <xs:element name="itemThreeResponse" type="genericResponse"/>

    <xs:complexType name="genericResponse">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="responseCode" type="xs:int"/>
            <xs:element name="errorCode" type="xs:int"/>
            <xs:element name="errorDescription" type="xs:string"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: Thnaks for this. So is this all within the one XSD, aka genericResponse.xsd?

Comment: It can be all in the same schema file, yes.

Answer (score 0):

Write a generic XSD document in which there is an element declaration for genericResponse defined with abstract="true".

Then write an XSD document for each message type, which uses xs:include to incorporate the generic XSD, and defines a specific element for the response, using subsitutionGroup="genericResponse" so that the specific element can be used in place of the abstract, generic one. If you don't specify a type for this element, then it will inherit the type of the genericResponse element. (Alternatively, you can give the custom element a type which extends or restricts the generic type.)

Individual messages should then be validated against the custom schema for the particular message type.